# Error in Realm Query at (wrapper managed-to-native) Realms.NativeTable.get_string

Tags: c#, database, xamarin, realm

I'm attempting to do a simple query on my first Realm database. I'm getting an error while trying to access the attributes of an object returned by my query method.
I have two questions:
 1. What's the meaning of this error? I'm having trouble to understand it...
 2. Am I doing the query the right way? If not, what am I doing wrong?

The error log:

```
[mono-rt] Stacktrace:

[mono-rt]   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>

[mono-rt]   at (wrapper managed-to-native) Realms.NativeTable.get_string >(Realms.TableHandle,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,bool&) <0x00057>

[mono-rt]   at Realms.RealmObject.GetStringValue (string) <IL 0x0009d, >0x00323>

[mono-rt]   at EasyVending.RCreditCard.get_holderName () <IL 0x0000e, 0x0006f>

[mono-rt]   at EasyVending.RealmManager.getCreditCard () [0x0001c] in /Users/Bernardo/Projects/EasyVending/EasyVending/DataBase/RealmManager.cs:75

[mono-rt]   at EasyVending.Android.CreditCartManagement.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00111] in /Users/Bernardo/Projects/EasyVending/EasyVending.Android/Activities/CreditCartManagement.cs:89

[mono-rt]   at Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00013, 0x000ff>

[mono-rt]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.13add723-97a5-4397-9c8a-e6fc23d98c3c (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00043>

[mono-rt]   at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.13add723-97a5-4397-9c8a-e6fc23d98c3c (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0001f, 0x00097>

[mono-rt] Attempting native Android stacktrace:

[mono-rt]  at ???+1 [0xbe903ac0]

[mono-rt]  at ???+1 [0x98f50ffc]

=================================================================

Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
[mono-rt] a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
[mono-rt] used by your application.
[mono-rt]

[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x97b77168 in tid 9849 (vending_android)
```

=====================================

```
public class RCreditCard : RealmObject {
    public string holderName { get; set; }
    public string bandeira { get; set; }
    public string digitos { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
}

public class RealmManager {
    private string databaseName {
        get {
            return "PayBluDatabase.db";
        }
    }
    private string androidPath {
        get {
            return Path.Combine (Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), databaseName);
        }
    }

    public Realm getRealm() {
        return Realm.GetInstance(androidPath);
    }

    public void closeRealm(Realm realm) {
        realm.Close();
    }

    public Transaction insertCreditCard(EasyVending.CreditCard creditCard) {
        var realm = getRealm();
        using(var transaction = realm.BeginWrite()) {
            var insertedCreditCard = realm.CreateObject<RCreditCard>();

            insertedCreditCard.holderName = creditCard.HolderName;
            insertedCreditCard.bandeira = creditCard.CreditCardBrand;
            insertedCreditCard.digitos = creditCard.MaskedCreditCardNumber;
            insertedCreditCard.token = creditCard.InstantBuyKey;

            transaction.Commit();
            closeRealm(realm);
            return transaction;
        }
    }

    public Transaction removeCreditCard() {
        var realm = getRealm();
        using(var transaction = realm.BeginWrite()) {
            realm.RemoveAll<RCreditCard>();
            transaction.Commit();
            closeRealm(realm);
            return transaction;
        }
    }

    public CreditCard getCreditCard() {
        var realm = getRealm();
        var rCreditCard = realm.All<RCreditCard>().First();
        closeRealm(realm);
        var creditCard = new CreditCard() {
            CreditCardBrand = rCreditCard.bandeira,
            MaskedCreditCardNumber = rCreditCard.digitos,
            HolderName = rCreditCard.holderName
        };
        return creditCard;
    }

    public bool hasCreditCard() {
        bool answer = false;
        var realm = getRealm();
        if(realm.All<RCreditCard>().Count() > 0) {
            answer = true;
        }
        closeRealm(realm);
        return answer;
    }
}
```

The error occurs when I try to access any attribute of the RCreditCard object returned by my query:

```
CreditCardBrand = rCreditCard.bandeira,
```

from

```
var rCreditCard = realm.All<RCreditCard>().First();
```

Please let me know if the question was not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you close the realm before you try to read the properties on `rCreditCard`in `getCreditCard()`. Properties in Realm objects are zero-copy, they access the database directly, so as soon as you close the realm, the object becomes invalid. We should handle this situation better, it's not clear at the moment. Thank you for pointing it out to us!

In general, you probably don't want to open and close the realm as often as you do, unless those calls take place on different threads. If you insist on doing this, you should move `Realm.Close()` calls outside of the transaction `using` scopes. As it is now, if something throws during the transaction, it will be rolled back but your realm will not be closed like you might expect.

Finally, having a "normal" class that mirrors your `RealmObject` class should generally not be necessary. Of course, there may be reasons why it is in your case, that aren't obvious here. Typically, you would use the `RealmObject` classes directly.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I did not know that by closing the realm the object becomes invalid..
Thanks for the explanation!
There is indeed a reason why I`m using a normal class that mirrors my realm object, but they have some differences.
Last of all, another question: What would I have to do if I wanted to return a rCreditCard on the method call? I should return it and leave an open realm?

Comment: Yes - leave the realm open, probably have it as a property in your model class.

Answer (score 1):

What Kristian said ;-)

Just to clarify, if you *must* open and close the Realm frequently, you can just do it with

```
using (var realm = getRealm()) {
// your update and read logic
}
```